# How to Display country name and statename on button title when page is loading

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, nsmutableurlrequest

My question is that when user press login button He is login to your account and then He select update user profile click all default data has been displayed and edit that data.

My response string look like this.

```
Response =     {
                    city = Rajkot;
                    "country_id" = 88;
                    dob = "1921-07-12";
                    gender = M;
                    "state_id" = 1371;
                    "user_id" = 22;
                     username = xyz;
                };
```

my viewDidLoad code******

```
NSURLResponse *response;

NSData *POSTReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];

NSString *theReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[POSTReply bytes] length:[POSTReply length] encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Reply: %@", theReply);

NSDictionary* dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:userid, nil] forKeys:[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Userid", nil]];

NSDictionary* dictMain = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"User",@"getUserProfileDetails",dict,nil] forKeys:[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Controller",@"Action",@"Arguments",nil]];

NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[dictMain JSONRepresentation]] ;

[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

city,dob,gender,username display proper. But how to display statename and countryname using their id?
I already sent request in viewDidLoad. When this page is load user also edit their value on that field.

So My problem is that to display a statename and countryname when page is load.....

Comment: There is no way to get the county and state name from just their ids. One way is to maintain these datas in a plist and you can write a helper class which will get the stored name from that plist. Or do you have a webservice which will return all the information of country and states if you pass country id?

Comment: I use web services...

Comment: These information are not going to change. You can persist them in the device itself. You can use plist. Everytime you check if there is some value stored in this plist, if not trigger a webservice fetch the data, store in plist. And you can try using block based asynchronous NSURLConnection for more cleaner code.